# What is the VB.NET equivalent of the C# “var” keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

E.g. how do I get VB.NET to **statically type** a local variable to be the **static** type of the expression on the right had side of the assignment?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like this:

> [Dim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx) myVar = 3

You'll also need

> [Option Infer On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx)

(At the top of the file or in project settings)

See "[Local Type Inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384937.aspx)"

Comment: Or "Option Infer On" in project settings, this can be set as the default through Tools->Options